# Google Maps - Add "Directions", "Search nearby" to info window

Tags: google-maps, django-cms

When I embed a Google Maps URL into my page I get an info window with some extra items in it like "Directions, "Search Nearby", and "More". I assume this is triggered by a param in the URL but I am not sure which.

[image]

The standalone URL:

```
<iframe width="100" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?client=safari&amp;oe=UTF-8&amp;q=5800+Blank+Road,+Sebastopol,+California+95472&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=5800+Blank+Rd,+Sebastopol,+California+95472&amp;gl=us&amp;t=h&amp;ll=38.342329,-122.79007&amp;spn=0.020196,0.008497&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe></div>
```

I am using Django CMS for a project and it has a Google Maps plugin as part of the core CMS, the only issue is the info windows just have the address and the client really like the other additional items.

I have gone through and made sure the plugin is calling the same URL as the standalone code but I still cannot seem to replicate

[image]

Comment: It is working for me. I get the directions etc.

Comment: Correct, the above static URL provides that info but when I try to use a google maps plugin in Django-CMS I only get the address, I am trying to figure out if I have to update the URL in the plugin with some extra params to get that info?

Comment: So you mean that you DON'T want to use the Iframe but the API? I think you need to add them manually. Don't think there is an option for it to turn those on.

Comment: Ahh ok thats what I was afraid of, wasn't sure if those extra info items were somehow triggered by something in the URL

Comment: And yes I was hoping to not use iFrame and use the standard Google Maps plugin in Django-CMS.